# Toggle-Button hide other elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve a filter that hides other divs by their class name.
So far I have the following code, which unfortunately doesn't work.
Please help me out, THX!!!

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="text to-filter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="text not-to-filter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<script>
 var button = document.getElementById('toggle'),
 text = Array.document.getElementsByClassName("text");
 button.onclick = function() {
   var isHidden = texts.style.display == 'none';
   text.forEach(function(){
    style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
   });
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will hide any elements that have the class `.to-filter` when the user clicks on `#toggle` the first time. When they click on it again it will show the elements again.

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.to-filter').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript version.

Add an 'onclick=toggleDiv()' attribute to the button and then,

```
function toggleDiv() {
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var status = text[i].style.display;
        text[i].style.display = (status=="" || status=="block") ? "none":"block";
    };
}
```

On click of the button, all 'text' class div will toggle on or off.